# jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

So after trying to get something to work I came up with this code (which allows for a more / less button that will stay open or closed whenever the page will be refreshed:

```
    var isCompactListOpen = localStorage.getItem('isCompactListOpen') || false;

    function setButtonText() {
        if (isCompactListOpen) {
            $(this).text('Show less');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Show more');
        }
    }

    if ($('.ty-compact-list').length > 3) {
    setButtonText();
    $('.show-more').show();
    if (!isCompactListOpen) {
        $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').hide();
        }
    }

    $('.show-more').on('click', function() {
    //toggle elements with class .ty-compact-list that their index is     bigger than 2
    $('.ty-compact-list:gt(2)').toggle();
    //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
    isCompactListOpen = !isCompactListOpen;
    localStorage.setItem('isCompactListOpen', isCompactListOpen);
    setButtonText();
    });
```

But now it gives me this error in the google chrome web console:

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
at dt (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:23993)
at Function.buildFragment (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:31426)
at init.domManip (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:28300)
at init.append (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:26162)
at init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as append] (http://dev.***.com/var/cache/misc/assets/js/tygh/scripts-4e16721e1fc39760420d82fb157574bd1483617255.js:681:688)
at init.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:25287)
at Function.access (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:6600)
at init.text (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:4:25224)
at setButtonText (http://dev.****.com/****/:4641:13)
at http://dev.****.com/****/:4646:3
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue may because you are using *this* instead of a selector. The *this* context is wrong in the *setButtonText* function.

Try this:

```
function setButtonText() {
    if (isCompactListOpen) {
        $('.show-more').text('Show less');
    } else {
        $('.show-more').text('Show more');
    }
}
```

Comment: you are my savior!

Comment: Just one more question though, it doesnt automatically show less items, it shows more untill you press show less. Can this be set to default in some way?

Comment: All you need to do is run the setButtonText function when the page loads.